# scale SVG d3.js (no event)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

this is my first post and I hope to not go wrong.
I'm using the library d3.js and I have a problem

Now place the base code that I use to create an SVG (d3).

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height"),
transform = d3.zoomIdentity;;

var g = svg.append("g");

svg.call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

I have put just one example of code that refers to Event Zoom.

Now I wanted to ask, how can I change the scale in my code with another type of event (for example, when I press a button I would like go back to position x: 0, y: 0 and scale k: 1)?

until now I have much studied the D3V4 source code, and I found with debuger some functions used by ZoomEvent, but I can not call them from my code.

then I also tried to directly modify the parameters with :

```
g.attr("transform", "translate(0,0) scale(1)");
```

this works but as soon as I create with mouse a zoom event, the library D3 returns to the old scale.

thank you and good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [zoom.transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_transform) for this (with `d3.zoomIdentity`) which in turn will fire the appropriate events updating the state of the transform:

Complete example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
  <br/>
  <button>reset zoom</button>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");
      
    var g = svg.append("g");
    
    g.append("text")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y", height/2)
      .text("Something to zoom...");
      
    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom);

    function zoomed() {
      g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }
    
    d3.select("button")
      .on("click", function(d){
        svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
      })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```